# Wordpress - Stripe Can I send a selected email after subscription?

Tags: wordpress, email, stripe-payments

I just added stripe to my wordpress website for 3 different monthly subscriptions. Is any way, so I can send a specific (that I select) email direct after the subscription? So, they can unlock some password locked posts in my website...

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not a feature provided by Stripe and would be the responsibility of your application to implement.